# Transactional Replication with LocalDB

Tags: sql-server, localdb, transactional-replication

I searched everywhere but couldn't find an answer. I know LocalDB cannot be a subscriber to merge replication. But what about transactional replication?

I've tried both the SQL Server Management Studio and RMO programming to create a pull subscription to a publication with type of transactional replication, but it keeps telling me "*replication is not installed on this instance of SQL server*". There is no option for me or the user to select replication feature during the install. And re-installing LocalDB won't do any help.

I know it is possible to use sync framework to do the job but it is something new to me and I've already deployed LocalDB to the clients computer in my previous software release, so I prefer to stick around with the replication method before I know for sure that LocalDB doesn't support any form of replication.

To summarize my question: **How do I create a pull subscription on a LocalDB instance to subscribe to a transactional replication?**

BTW, the LocalDB is deployed to the clients computers using the bootstrapper came with Windows 8 SDK, which can be found in this directory if you have one installed: {C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlLocalDB2012}

I would be happy to provide more information if I didn't make it clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why someone down vote this question? What's the problem?

Comment: I agree. Downvote n@zis are everywhere.

Comment: did you tried push subscription ?

Comment: Good question and still no answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question: "How do I create a pull subscription on a LocalDB instance to subscribe to a transactional replication?", the answer is simple. You can't.

Setting up a pull subscription requires replication components to be installed (they're not), and requires Agent to be installed (it's not).

I think you have a reasonable chance of getting a push subscription set up, as all the serious code happens on the distributor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, I find in your question is that you were not able to setup transactional replication in a Local DB instance.

I want to add my work on Transactional Replication.

Recently, I created Two Local SQL Server instances. I setup Transactional replication among these two SQL Server instances without any problem. I hope this helps. Please comment if there is any question on this.